# Application crashes when I switch to a different XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

Hi I'm a novice in writing C# applications.

Sorry if its too basic. 
I have a thread running in Main xaml which queries for some information and updates a property.

So once I detect that property is set to "X" I need to switch to a different XAML view.

The problem I'm facing is when I invoke the switch from the Property, my app crashes.
I think it has to do with the thread..

Qn : How do I switch to a different XAML view as soon as I detect the property value changed?

Sample Code :

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

```
     ....
    private Thread t;
    public static enState dummy;

    public enState SetSTATE
    {
       get
       {
            return dummy;
       }
       set
       {
             dummy = value;
             if (dummy == A )
             {
                   var NEWVIEW = new  VIEW1();
                    contentGrid.Children.Add(NEWVIEW);      // - crashes in this block
              }
       }
     }

    public void startThread()
    {
      t = new Thread(getInfo);
      t.Isbackground = true;
      t.start();
    }

    public void getInfo()
    {
        while (true)
       {
            int x = somefunc();
           if (x == conditon)
           {
                SetSTATE = A;
           }
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }
    }
    MainWindow() { startThread(); }
```

}

---

public partial class NEWVIEW: UserControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a collection from a background thread.  You'll need to explicitly use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to make the modification:

```
if (dummy == A )
{
    contentGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        var NEWVIEW = new  VIEW1();
        contentGrid.Children.Add(NEWVIEW);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reed. It worked.. Can you recommend any good book for learning these ?

Comment: @GanapathySubramanian Basically, you always have to do this if you want to modify UI elements from a background thread.  With WPF, only collections need this.